# Slim 3 How to get the Post mothod body

Tags: php, json, slim

I make a post using **form data** `id = 1` and use getparams method like this `$request->getParams('id')` i get the id.

Now i make a query via **Json**

> POST localhost/books_example/public/apiv1

Body is:

> {"id": "1"}

Here `$request->getParams('id')` , `$request->getParams()` and `$request->getBody()` are not work. Now, how can i get the id parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the request body from `php://input` and pass it to `json_decode()`.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

The value you are looking for will be in `$data->id`.

Comment: Yes. It's work. Thanks.On the other hand **$request->getParsedBody()['id'];** too work for me.